# .toFixed() not working

Tags: javascript

im using this code

```
$('tr').each(function () {
                var td = $(this).children('td').eq(1);
                var val = td.html();
                if (val > 1000) {

                    var fixedVal = parseFloat(parseFloat(val).toFixed(3));
                    td.html(fixedVal / 1000 + " KM");
                }
                else {
                    td.html(Math.round(val) + " M");
                }
            });
```

and yet iam getting values like

```
3.5101280000000004 KM
8761.596300000001 KM
```

the problem is that `.toFixed()` is not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first *fix* the number and then you divide it by *1000*, which creates a new floating point number. Call `toFixed` in your `.html()` line instead.

```
var fixedVal = parseFloat( val );
td.html( (fixedVal / 1000).toFixed( 3 ) + " KM" );
```